# How to encode and decode URL to $link = $_GET['url']; variable?

Tags: javascript, php, sha1

I want to encode urls to be transferred decoded to this variable:
`$link = $_GET['url'];`

Normally I use my php file like this: mysite.com/view.php?url=http://othersite.com/file/123
I want the link **http://othersite.com/file/123** to be encoded using some encryption and then decoded into my  php file **view.php** to be passed to `$link = $_GET['url'];` without errors.

How can I do this, step-by-step? Thanks.

Comment: SHA1 is hash function and theres no decode function... so only way you could achive this is create table of posibilities and match result of SHA1 with input string and then search throught that table find if some of your record match `$_GET['url']` if so then by index get the original string

Comment: i dont know what you do with variable `$link` but if you use function which has decode function then everyone could pass whatever he want and it will be pointless

Comment: I just want to hide the link http://othersite.com/file/123

Comment: if you use `encryption` and `decryption` with key who know only `mysite.com` and `othersite.com` then it could work as you want

Comment: @MarekJanoud Tutorial? Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm starting in php.

Comment: and is there constant list of urls or are they relative ?

Comment: @MarekJanoud They're relative! You mean their protocols right?

Comment: no, but first things first, why you need to pass link to othersite by get method ?

Comment: @MarekJanoud I use it with an iframe! And it's very important that nobody knows my source link. That's normally easy to find on viewing source page or simply inspecting in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple way:

```
// view.php
$sources = [
    'secretString' => 'http://othersite.com/file/123',
    'secretString2' => 'http://othersite.com/file/1234',
    'secretString3' => 'http://othersite.com/file/12345'
    //etc..
];

if(isset($_GET['url']) && isset($sources[$_GET['url']])){
    $link = $sources[$_GET['url']];
}

if(isset($link)){
    // do something
}
```

url is: `mysite.com/view.php?url=secretString`

btw if you have list then it could be done as you want in the first place like this:

```
// view.php
$sources = [
    'http://othersite.com/file/123',
    'http://othersite.com/file/1234',
    'http://othersite.com/file/12345'
    //etc..
];

if(isset($_GET['url'])){
    foreach($sources as $source){
        if(sha1($source) == $_GET['url']){
            $link = $source;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(isset($link)){
    // do something
}

//...

echo '<iframe src="mysite.com/view.php?url='.sha1('http://othersite.com/file/123').'"></iframe>';
```

external file examples:

txt file:

```
http://othersite.com/file/123
http://othersite.com/file/1234
http://othersite.com/file/12345
```

reading:

```
$sources = explode("\n", file_get_contents('path/to/file.txt'));
```

or by php:

```
// sources.php for example
return [
    'secretString' => 'http://othersite.com/file/123',
    'secretString2' => 'http://othersite.com/file/1234',
    'secretString3' => 'http://othersite.com/file/12345'
    //etc..
];
```

reading:

```
$sources = include('sources.php');
```

or just:

```
// sources.php for example
$sources = [
    'secretString' => 'http://othersite.com/file/123',
    'secretString2' => 'http://othersite.com/file/1234',
    'secretString3' => 'http://othersite.com/file/12345'
    //etc..
];

// in view.php
require_once('sources.php');
```

Comment: How can I do this with multiple urls? I have a great list of urls to use with my php like this one.

Comment: How are them accessible through url?

Comment: One another question, should I need to remove the $link = $_GET['url']; from my php?

Comment: yes value is set to `$link` variable in code i post

Comment: You rocks man! It's insane! It worked for me, thank you so much my brother of soul!

Comment: Is there a good way to separate the sources to another file in my server? So I can create a file with the list only instead of inserting the sources into my view.php.

Comment: it doesnt matter actually, its up to you

Comment: Truly it matter a bit, because my view.php file will be large, inserting a lot of links on it, and it should be slower in loading.

Comment: no it will be a bit slower when they are in external file

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look by myself on this, it's working well!